# Почему приложение не запускается на планшете?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Такая ситуация есть приложение когда я делаю `run` в `android studio` то я вижу, что прогресс билда заканчивается и приложение сразу должно открыться на устройстве. Но этого не происходит.

Я вижу, что иконка приложения появляется на планшете и я могу ее запустить, но проблема в том, что я не могу делать в таком случае дебаг... так как при дебаг моде приложение должно открыться сразу после билда и тогда все работает если я открываю приложение с устройства вручную то дебаг не работает

И я заметил, что эта ситуация только с планшетом, на телефоне все открывается и работает как положено

Что это может быть?

Если что то пропустил, спрашивайте

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Данная проблема известна давно, но конкретной причины я найти не смог, скорее всего это связано с кастомизацией `Android-системы` у производителей устройств. Это смело можно отнести к категории багов.

Как вариант можно воспользоваться [советом](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33938532/6608568) от [@suba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5607392/suba).

Также есть великолепная кнопка в `Android Studio` - `Attach debugger to Android process` (прикрепить дебагер к андроид-процессу).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Её необходимо использовать при работающем приложении. Дебаг в этом случае работает точно так же как и запуск в `DEBUG_MODE`

Comment: оо спасибо! но все равно интересно почему так себя ведет , почему сразу не запускает

Answer (score 1):

Может быть у вас в коде есть что-то типа такой строчки:

```
setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

У меня возникала такая же проблема когда планшет располагался в горизонтальном положении (то есть ориентации `LANDSCAPE`) из-за вышеуказанной строки. Эта строка требуется, если вы хотите изменить ориентацию экрана на портретный.

В моём случае мне нужен был всегда портретный режим. Для этого я удалил эту строку в всех активити. И в AndroidManifest.xml у каждого активити дописал  `android:screenOrientation="portrait"`.

Пример:

```
<activity
android:name=".SettingsActivity"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```